# How to use index function in VBA to a dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel

I got a `n x m data array` and I'm trying to compute the average value of a subset of that array without using a loop.

In excel, I can use for example:

```
x = AVERAGE(INDEX(A1:A100,20,1):INDEX(A1:A100,50,3))
```

But not sure how to convert this into VBA. The following will give me an error:

```
x = Worksheetfunction.Average(Worksheetfunction.Index(ArrayX,20,1):Worksheetfunction.Index(ArrayX,50,3))
```

I'm assuming I cannot just use `":"` in between the functions. How can I get around it? Appreciate the help!

Comment: If ArrayX is actually an array, you can't. If it's a `Range`, construct another `Range` from desired cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Application.Index` to extract subsets of your array by passing an array of row and column numbers:

```
x = WorksheetFunction.Average(Application.Index(ArrayX, [row(20:32)], Array(1, 2, 3)))
```

Note that `WorksheetFunction.Index` will not work for this, you must use `Application.Index`. Also, there is a limit of 65536 'rows' for your array.

Comment: Thanks for responding. It works when the inputs for row() are actual numbers, but when they are variables, I get the Run-time error 1004: Unable to get the Average property of the WorksheetFunction class. For instance, row(12:24) works, but row(m:n), where m = 12, n = 24, does not. In my code, m and n are determined via the Count function. Anyway round this? Thanks again!

Comment: Use `Evaluate("ROW(" & m & ":" & n & ")")`